# how to speed up this R function with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to write out a lot of text files with a loop in R, but I do not know how to speed up it with Rcpp?
test data and R function are as follow:

```
mywrite<- function(data,dataid){
  for(i in unique(dataid$id)) {
    yearid=data[["year"]][i==data[["id"]]]
    for(yr in yearid) {
      fname=paste(i,sprintf("%03d",yr%%1000),sep=".")
      write.table(dataid[i,],file=fname,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
      write.table(subset(data,year==yr&id==i),file=fname,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
    }
  }
}

data=data.frame(id=rep(1:5,4),year=rep(1991:2000,2),x=rep(1,40),y=rep(1,40))
dataid=data.frame(id=1:5,lat=31:35,lon=101:105)
mywrite(data,dataid)
```

PS:it takes about 50 minutes using R for writing out such 30000 text files, while only 10 minutes using FORTRAN.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I don't think there is much potential to improve this using Rcpp since your bottleneck is probably writing to disk,

Comment: How many id's and years do you have in your real data set and how many records do you have (on average) for each year-id combination?

Comment: it takes about 50 minutes using R for writing out such 30000 text files, while only 10 minutes using FORTRAN.so,I think it will be faster with Rcpp.

Comment: See the help for `write.table` for hints on speeding up the process. In particular, you might want to turn your data into a matrix before writing it out.

Comment: Yes, I have tried cat and as.matrix function in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a 4x speedup by eliminating all the redundant `subset`ing in the loop, and using a split-apply strategy instead:

```
mywrite2<- function(data,dataid){
  by(data, interaction(data$year, data$id), function(x){
             i <- x$id[1]
             yr <- x$year[1]
             fname=paste(i,sprintf("%03d.2",yr%%1000),sep=".")
             write.table(dataid[i,],file=fname,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
             write.table(x, file=fname, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE) 
          })
}


> require(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+ mywrite(data,dataid)
+ ,
+ mywrite2(data,dataid)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
  mywrite(data, dataid) 76.613679 77.4709100 78.86304895 78.0260815 78.7791595 128.463443   100
 mywrite2(data, dataid) 18.894828 19.1707455 20.12820819 19.4053135 21.2940880  23.101325   100
```

This will probably get it in the ballpark of your fortran code, no Rcpp required.

Comment: Its great,Thanks!
and I have fixed it as write.table(as.matrix(x), ……
But I think there need a subset for dataid[i,]  (in write.table(dataid[i,],)
May be it can be done with dplyr package(using group_by)